# BeanInitializationException: Property is required for bean

Tags: spring, spring-batch, job-scheduling, spring-scheduled

I'm getting:

```
BeanInitializationException: Property 'job' is required for bean 'jobScheduler'
```

even though I have a "batch:job" bean properly defined and I have a property declaration pointing to it like below:

```
<batch:job id="userSummary">
    ...
</batch:job>

<bean id="jobScheduler" class="cc.glance.server.business.fact.JobScheduler">
    <property name="job" ref="userSummary" />
</bean>
```

Note: There shouldn't be a problem with the definition of "userSummary" because It worked fine before, when I was calling it via web controller instead of scheduling.

Stack trace:

```
2014-05-14 11:54:08,022 | ERROR | ion(5)-127.0.0.1 | o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/]                | apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog  185 | Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobScheduler' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/VICTOR/TRABALHO/glance/glance-core/server/glance-server-webapp/target/glance-server-webapp-2.2.2-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/glance-server-business-2.2.2-SNAPSHOT.jar!/cc/glance/server/business/fact/JobScheduler.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Property 'job' is required for bean 'jobScheduler'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547) ~[spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) ~[spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304) ~[spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300) ~[spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195) ~[spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700) ~[spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760) ~[spring-context-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482) ~[spring-context-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:381) ~[spring-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:293) ~[spring-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) ~[spring-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1740) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.53]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.53]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:618) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:565) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.53]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.53]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1487) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:97) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1420) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:848) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:553) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:808) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:667) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Property 'job' is required for bean 'jobScheduler'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:156) ~[spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185) ~[spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537) ~[spring-beans-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    ... 54 common frames omitted
```

JobScheduler class:

```
@Component
public class JobScheduler
{
    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    private Job job;

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Required
    public void setJob(Job job)
    {
        this.job = job;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            Date endDate = new Date();
            Date beginDate = DateUtils.addWeeks(endDate, -1);
            String summaryId = beginDate.toString(); //TODO proper summaryId

            JobParametersBuilder builder = new JobParametersBuilder();
            builder.addDate("dateFrom", beginDate);
            builder.addDate("dateTo", endDate);
            builder.addString("summaryId", summaryId);

            JobParameters param = builder.toJobParameters();

            JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, param);
            logger.info("Exited UserSummary job scheduling with status: " + execution.getStatus());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the full stack trace.

Comment: Please post class cc.glance.server.business.fact.JobScheduler

Comment: Thanks. Stack trace and JobScheduler class added.

Comment: How do you wire all together? I mean, I see a `@Component` for `JobScheduler` and I see that piece of XML file, but how do you mix all these together? (what app context are you using, how are you creating it etc)

Comment: @AndreiStefan On web.xml there's reference to a ApplicationContextInitializer that takes a ConfigurableWebApplicationContext. Is that what you need?
I'm not sure what info to give you. I'm on a big project with many modules. Each module has a bunch of spring xml files, one of them is called applicationContext. It runs on tomcat.

Comment: Along with Required Anotation , you need to add Annotation Autowired

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, as @AndreiStefan suggested, on how spring XML files are being loaded.

The XML I copied here (with the "userSummary" job and "jobScheduler" bean) was not being loaded. It was only being referenced from another XML that set it to an "AutomaticJobRegistrar" which scans it for jobs (only jobs, no other beans). That's why it worked from my web controller as I noted in the question. Now the "jobScheduler" bean I defined there is not a job, so it's not loaded as I wanted with the property set.

Now I had annotated my JobScheduler class as @Component. That's why the context still loads it, although without the required property, thus raising the exception.

To fix the problem I moved the "jobScheduler" definition to another XML that is being loaded by the context (it's on a folder referenced by an import from applicationContext.xml).

Answer (score 0):

To answer a similar problem as @Vituel.  To be a bit more specific I was both loading a bean as defined in the XML file *and* with specifying it as `@Component`.  Even though I was defining the properties appropriately, they were coming up as required and not specified:

```
<bean id="newMappingFileController" class="...NewMappingFileController">
    <property name="sasMappingBO" ref="sasMappingBO" />
</bean>
...
Error...
Caused by: ...BeanInitializationException: Property 'sasMappingBO' is required...
```

The solution for me was simply to remove the `@Component` annotation from the class and things worked.